# How to use JavaScript Loop to return spaces for duplicate values after first duplicate value

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
var a = ['green','green','green','yellow','yellow','yellow','white','blue']
```

And I will display the array in a loop and the output should be:

```
green


yellow


white
blue
```

It should have space. for example 3 green and it should be display 1 green and next is 2 space or line break

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck? Will your input always be sorted like that? What if you had `green, green, yellow, green`? How is that supposed to be handled? Or is that not a possible input?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to achieve this:

```js
var a = ['green','green','green','yellow','yellow','yellow','white','blue'];
let set = new Set();
for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
     if(!set.has(a[i])){
          console.log(a[i]);
          set.add(a[i]);
     }else{
          console.log(" ");
     }
}
```

Comment: I would not use a set here, as it is not needed and has a higher complexity and it _seems_ to be a simple "preceding value" style problem. Of course, given input and test case of `["foo", "bar", "bar", "foo"]` eg. would really be needed..

Comment: @user2864740 OP did not specify that the array is always sorted. If it is, the solution would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a variable for the last value and check against.

```js
var array = ['green', 'green', 'green', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'white', 'blue'],
    last;
    
for (const value of array) console.log(value === last ? '' : last = value);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```